# Регулярное выражение для стилей, в формате ключ-значение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Приветствую, не могу подобрать регулярное выражение что-бы preg_match_all разделял строку на массив с названием параметра и его значением. Текущий вариант, правильно разбивает параметры, но они разбиваются целиком. Как должна выглядеть правильное выражение?

```
$row = 'top:223px;left:103px;font-weight: 300; text-transform: uppercase;font-family:Roboto Condensed;font-size:48px;white-space: nowrap;" data-ls="offsetxin:0;delayin:500;offsetxout:0;';
preg_match_all("/([\s\S]*?)*:([\s\S]*?);/", $row, $InnerContent);
```

Comment: что вы хотите на выходе получить то? не проще тут `explode()` сделать и обойтись без регулярных выражений?

Comment: @teran Нужен массив в формате ключ-значение, и `explode() ` придется делать 2 раза сначала на `;` а потом на `:`. Что не очень красиво. Регулярным выражением можно управится проще.

Comment: главное не утомиться поддерживать код потом, а то сначала регулярка проще чем explode, затем станет лень именовать переменные и методы и так далее.

Comment: @teran У меня большие сомнения, что формат входящих данных в будущем будет меняться :)

Comment: А что не так с текущим выражением ? что означает "разбиваются целиком" ? судя по тому что тут у вас на выходе должен быть массив в котором [0]=>массив полных вхождений, [1]=>массив первых скобок, [2]=>массив вторых скобок

Comment: @Mike пустой там массив группы `[1]` на выходе

Comment: @teran Звездочку прямо перед двоеточием уберите, а то получается что первые скобки не обязательны

Comment: @Mike это автор пусть убирает. а мне и варианта `(.+?):(.+?);` достаточно

Comment: @Mike Да, вы правы. Если убрать звездочку в оригинальном выражении, то все будет работать как надо.

Comment: @Happy_Cougar, можно еще сделать так: `(?:([^:;]+))` - меньше сожрет памяти, будет 1 массив, который в итоге вы разобьете по 2 - свойства<>значения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[\s\S]` - это пробельный символ либо любой кроме пробельного. т.е. любой!

Делайте так:

```
preg_match_all("/([^:;]*):([^:;]*)(?:;|$)/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

`(?:;|$)` - это точка с запятой либо конец строки.

[Онлайн тест](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/iIF)

Comment: там `*?` следовательно `[\s\S]` берет ровно до двоеточия, а проблема исключительно в единственной не нужной звездочке перед этим самым двоеточем

Comment: @Mike Да, такое может вызвать catastrophical backtracking. Хотя дело не в этом, конечно. Я добавил еще возможность взять последнее значение без `;` в конце

Comment: тут пробелы, наверное, будут в ключи попадать, что врядли желательно. То есть будет не `text-transform` а `_text-transform`

Comment: @Crantisz Можете привести входную строку которая бы привела к бактрекингу. по тестам на regex101 и ваше выражение и `(.*?):(.*?);` дают одинаковое количество шагов как на нормальном примере так и на кривых

Comment: концовку лучше в `[;|$]` сделать, смысла собирать третью группу соответствий нет.

Comment: @teran Не покатит. квадратные скобки рассмотрят `$` как доллар, а не конец строки. `(?:;|$)` что бы не собирало

Comment: @Mike, действительно, спасибо за поправку.

Answer (score -1):

Можно и без регулярки через explode

```
$result = array();

foreach(explode(';', $row) as $_params) {
   list($key, $value) = explode(':', $_params);
   $result[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Для более лучшей производительности, нужно задействовать 3 параметр функции `explode` иначе очень медленно будет при больших данных.

Comment: @And а что предлагается писать в третий параметр?

Comment: @teran - по умолчанию этот параметр имеет `PHP_INT_MAX` - максимальный лимит.  Кстате еще минус, не желательно при каждой итерации цикла `foreach` дергать `explode` - желательно первый `explode` определить в переменную выше цикла, а второму сказать. что только лимит 2 (больше массив не может быть).

Comment: @And я знаю, что `PHP_INT_MAX`. Вы говорите про большие данные, но это может относиться только к первому `explode` где строка действительно может быть длинной, во втором всегда будет короткая строка. В `foreach` `explode`, очевидно, вызывается однократно при первой итерации. Вот собственно и вопрос возникает, имхо, указание последнего аргумента как 2, может быть полезно только когда у нас строка на 10 мегабайт, и символ разделитель встречается всего один раз, и это происходит ближе к началу. В противном случае, я не понимаю, чем указание максимального числа элементов может помочь.

Comment: @teran, тратится время на вызов функции при каждой итерации и других последсвий в функции, нежели когда мы определили ее сразу в переменной. последний аргумент нам поможет указать лимит и не будет сразу выделять память на весь размер.

Comment: @And Он выполнит explode только один раз, пример http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7261f2d5e6a9f917f47f39d640553ef2ca911eee

Comment: @Naumov, сначала загляните `standard/string.c` и тогда поймете о чем я говорю. Он будет каждый раз вызывать функцию explode при каждой итерации. нежели единожды при определении ее в переменной и только потом читать переменную при каждой итерации.

Comment: @And загляните по ссылке, там пример и foreach выполняет естевственно функцию один раз. Точнее выполняется функция, возвращает массив и массив уже интерируеться, foreach может интерировать только массив и объекты, он не может интерировать функцию...

Comment: @And ну кидайте доки на "ваши" стандарты, и как работает интерпретатор?

Comment: Я же дал, так сказать ссылку, изучите структуру функции. Вбейте в гугл, исходник даже найдете =) А вообще вы не понимаете принципа - он в любом случае дергает функцию explode. А в случае определения в переменной он работает по другому.

Comment: @And этот коментарий видимо кто то удалил уже, дайте ссылку ещё раз? и приведите реальный пример где foreach каждый раз вычисляет выражение.

Comment: @Naumov, Тут так не принято общаться в комментариях, меня уведомляют, постоянно.  Комментарий удалил я. Я ранее написал про страндарт, выше комментарий. - Некоторые говорят `незначительная погрешность` - когда вы столкнетесь с реальным объемом инфы, вы увидите каждую погрешность. - Это лишь размышления в сторону не высоконагруженных или даже не продуктивных сайтов. А в более масштабных проектах требуется более оптимизированный скрипт-код.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52581/discussion-between-naumov-and-and).